# No module named 'Dajaxice'

Tags: dajaxice, dajax

**import in HTML:**

```
<script src="/media/js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dajax.core.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function oneri()
{
    Dajaxice.rezervationApp.oneri(Dajax.process)
}
</script>
```

I use:

```
 <div class="span6"> <a href="#adviceModal" class="btn" role="button" onClick="oneri()" data-toggle="modal">Öneri Al</a></div>
```

**in ajax.py**

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from django.shortcuts import render
from rezervationApp.models import RoomType, Room, Market, Profile, Reservation


@dajaxice_register
def oneri(request, word):
    dajax = Dajax()
    p = Profile.objects.get(firstname__contains=word)
    dajax.assign('#advice','innerHTML', p)
    return dajax.json()
```

Fully error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named 'Dajaxice'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'Dajaxice'
Exception Location: C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\dajaxice\core\__init__.py in <module>, line 3
```

But, always same error.
I configured other file as dajax tutorial.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in difference between py2 and py3. Py3 allows *only explicit* relative imports.
It works when you add a dot.

```
from .Dajaxice import Dajaxice, dajaxice_autodiscover
```

Comment: My app is hosted on heroku, is there any way to modify the __init__.py? Or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly the Dajaxice tutorial leaves out the part where you actually have to install Dajaxice...

If you haven't already you should try `pip install django-dajaxice`

Answer (score 0):

Just install the dajax package using the below command.

pip3 install dajax
pip3 install django-dajaxice
(If the Python version is 3 or more than that)

pip install dajax

Answer (score -1):

If that is your generated HTML then there's where the problem lies. If you followed the Dajaxice set up tutorial on their documentation, you probably used `{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}
{% dajaxice_js_import %}` in the head of your templates. This is supposed to generate a static dajaxice.core.js file where your static folder is and show you something like `<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="/static/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js">` in your generated HTML.

If you have followed the installation steps for both Dasjax and Dajaxice exactly then define a STATIC_ROOT setting in your settings.py as the location of your static root folder (relative to the settings.py file) and then run `python manage.py collectstatic` this should give you 200 and eventually 304 responses for the Dajaxice javascript file and your app should run just fine.